# How can I automatically extend edge loop selection?

Tags: selection-tools, edges, topology

I have a cylinder that I erased some faces near the middle of it on the side like this.
[image]

However I when I <kbd>Alt</kbd> click the edge of it, it doesn't go completely around the new edge like this:

[image]

What I automatically want it to do is this (I just custom selected all the edges to show you what I mean):

[image]

So is there anyway to add edges to the edge loop without clicking every single one?

Comment: I think you are asking about selecting edges, so I edited your title. If this is incorrect, feel free to roll back the changes.

Comment: Look good to me. Than you for taking the time and simplifying the post!! (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select all the faces in that mesh and choose *Select> Select Boundary Loop* from the 3D view header menu you will get the selection you want.

You can also <kbd>Alt</kbd>-Click the initial edge and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>-Click the next set of edges.

Comment: *"I don't think it's possible to use the standard edge loop selection and tell it to continue to other edges automatically "* - This isn't correct, **Alt+RMB** twice selects all boundary edges (as noted by @Leon Cheung)

Answer (score 10):

Since the target edges are all boundaries, there are multiple ways to do this:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> **twice** on a boundary extends the selection to all boundary edges.
  *For single boundary loop as shown in the example*

Other ways to select boundaries.

- In **Vertex Select** or **Edge Select** mode: **3D View** menu > **Select** -> **Non Manifold** 
  (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>).
- Or you can first select all elements, then go to **3D View** menu > **Select** > **Select Boundary Loop**.

Comment: I had already posted the first solution as an answer, but the second solution is also good.

Comment: @William I wonder if the updated answer here be the quickest way for you?

Comment: For sure. The keyboard shortcut is way faster, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You have to change the [edge flow](https://vimeo.com/9146369) of the edge to make the selection go around the way you are look for it to.

By spiting the corner in to two quads that "bend" around the corner you will make the flow go around. Do note that it has to be two quads, two triangles will not work.
[image: two quads]

As you can see by adding a new edge loop the edge flow now goes around the whole edge.
[image: adding a new edge loop]

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that you can always select your first vertex or edge, then hold [Ctrl] and click anywhere else the same loop.

Blender will then automatically select the edges between.
This would do what you want with just four mouse clicks, and is more generally useful and somewhat easier to remember than other methods. :)